# Use 2 objects of same class

Tags: drools

I am new to Drools and have to compare value of 2 objects of same class.
i.e. let's say the class is

```
public class Person() {
    public string Name;
}
```

So I want to compare person1's name and person2's name and throw an exception if they are equal.
It would be great if someone can give an example of the same.

Answer (score 1):

That can easily be done with a rule similar to this:

```
rule 'Unique Names'
when
    $p1: Person()
    Person(this != $p1, name == $p1.name)
then
    //error
end
```

I would discourage you to simply throw an exception in the `then` part of the rule though. It is a better idea to collect your results somewhere and then validate those results outside Drools.

Comment: +1 ... especially for not throwing an exception in the `then` clause.  It might be worth mentioning, though, that if there's no `retract` or other control flow action that happens, the rule will hit twice -- once for each Person instance.